# Jquery Validation Plugin Name Conflict with Zend_Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, plugins, zend-form

By default, Zend_Form creates a hidden input field for each checkbox input in the form.  These inputs share the same name.

```
<input type="hidden" name="zend-cb" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="zend-cb" id="zend-cb" value="1">
```

I want to require the checkbox, so I set up the following rule in my jquery plugin validator (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/):

```
'zend-cb': {
  required: true
}
```

Unfortunately, the Jquery Validation plugin always validates the hidden field instead of the checkbox.  Is there a way I can have it validate the checkbox instead?  I realize I could change my Zend Decorator to omit the hidden field, but I'd like to find a pure javascript solution.

**Solution**

Two steps are needed to get around this problem.

1)  Add ignore: "input[type=hidden]" as an option to the validate method.

```
$('#myForm').validate( {
   ignore: "input[type=hidden]",
   rules: { ... }
}
```

2) Open jquery.validate.js and update the findByName method to use the ignore filter.  Bug report filed by adamnfish on the jquery plugin site.

[findByName does not honour ignore settings](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/9234)

```
findByName: function( name ) {
        // select by name and filter by form for performance over form.find("[name=...]")
        var form = this.currentForm;
        return $(document.getElementsByName(name)).not(this.settings.ignore).map(function(index, element) {
            return element.form == form && element.name == name && element  || null;
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ignore` option of the validation plugin.

```
$("#yorform").validate({
    ...
    ignore: "input[type=hidden]"
})
```

This should for example stop the plugin from validating any hidden inputs

Check the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) for more info

Comment: wow easy solution.  somehow I missed that option.  appreciate it greatly!

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to completely fix the problem.  I'm investigating a fix entitled "findByName does not honour ignore settings," found here:  http://plugins.jquery.com/node/9234

Comment: Your fix in combination with the fix on the bug report seems to solve the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting find. Thx for the issue tracker url